# Getting blank corners in custom view Android

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
            <padding
            android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"

            />


            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am using this as a custom background. I want rounded corners in this with the same color was that of border. But when I apply corners I get blank spaces in corners. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
        <padding
        android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp"

        />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I need to use the above layout for specific purpose since I need one layout with border on 3 sides merged with a layout with border on one side.

Answer (score 0):

I think You Forgot to add **radius** in that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#cccccc" />
            <padding
            android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp"

            />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I have used it ,do I need to use it anywhere else than where I have ?

Comment: I am saying I have already used it in my original code,but do I need to use it in some other tag?

Comment: Other tag! what do u want to acheive

Comment: I am merging two layouts like this , with one having border on three sides and another one on only one side ,  on addition to that all four sides needs to have rounded borders.

Comment: But I am getting the corners as blank. If I use simple <shape tag with corners then I achieve the result , but I can't do it since it is not a single layout. I need to use two simultaneously with 3 in one and a single in other.

Answer (score 0):

The whole drawable file should be like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <padding
      android:bottom="0dp"
      android:left="0dp"
      android:right="0dp"
      android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

just adjust the corner radius depending on what you like.

If you are looking for adjusting the radius of other corners
add something like this.

```
<corners 
android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp" 
android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp" 
android:topLeftRadius="5dp" 
android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
```

just adjust the value depending on where do you need it to be rounded.

Comment: I need to use my layout for specific purpose,since I need borders on only three sides.

Comment: use this?
<corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
      android:topRightRadius="5dp" />